# How to resize a window correctly (libGDX)?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to create the main menu screen from my game. I added a table with some buttons and labels on it.
When I'm resizing to windowed mode, the inputs don't work anymore (they work when I don't resize the window).

I'm trying to figure a correct way out, how I scale my window correctly, but nothing seems to be working.

I scaled the stage with the following code:

```java
stage.getCamera().position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2, 0);
```

`java resize(int width, int height)` is empty.

Comment: Hi Benny, I found a solution that could help you: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86241/libgdx-desktop-windows-resize

Comment: Thanks, @DEX7RA for the answer! Sadly this didn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just took a ruff overview. I think the problem is that the game doesn't update it's layout with the set buttons etc.. Try to add this snippet of code:

```
stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
```

For further explanations take a look at this [documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d).

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)